# How do I check whether all code paths return a value

Tags: compiler-construction, semantics

I am writing a compiler for an embedded scripting language that will run in my application. I am currently working on the semantic analysis portion of the compiler. I would like to know, in theory, how to check that all code paths in a given script will return a value. Doing a [Google search](http://bit.ly/1gSZTPw) yields only results about people seeing the error in their own code when not all code paths return a value (mostly SO questions), so I have been unable to find sources that explain how the actual checking can be done.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**NOTE:**
I am specifically looking for an authoritative source outlining a rigorous algorithm, if at all possible.

Comment: An alternative approach that I think should be mentioned is to have *all* statements return a value. Then the problem vanishes by design.

Comment: @KubaOber I had considered this, but I prefer the convention of forcing the programmer to use a return statement in order to reduce the likelihood of programming errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive walk over the AST. For example:

- A sequence of statements returns on all control paths if either the first statement returns on all control paths or the second statement returns on all control paths.
- An if statement returns on all control paths if both the "if" and "else" branches return on all control paths or the "if" statement is always true.
- A while loop returns on all control paths only if the "while" condition is always true.
- A return statement returns on all control paths.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. But I was hoping for a more rigorous algorithm, perhaps something out of a CS textbook. I couldn't find anything in the Dragon Book, and other compiler textbooks I've picked up.

Comment: What I've described should be pretty easy to convert to a top-down recursive descent over an AST, the same way you'd compute types for expressions.

Comment: I think it would be simple, but I'm looking for rigorous. I want to know that what I'm implementing is absolutely rock solid.

Comment: If you're looking for an authoritative reference, you should probably update the question to ask for a link to an existing trusted resource.

Comment: @MrCodeMnky If you want rigorous, you probably want to be describing your language in terms of formal semantics, and then the properties you're after become proofs in some logic. Your problem then reduces to one of doing proofs in a logic, and there are multiple techniques for such proofs, depending on what logic is involved. Most likely you'd be doing structural induction on the syntax tree, see e.g. [here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~amp12/papers/alpsri/alpsri.pdf).

Comment: That's much more labor intensive than I am looking for, and I don't need such strong guarantees. Maybe I should just accept @templatetypedef's answer and be glad I got a helpful hint :)

Comment: @templatetypedef For while loops, what if it's a do-while? Can I say that it returns on all code paths if it's a do-while and it has a return statement, even if the condition is not always true? Thanks.

Comment: @MrCodeMnky definitely.

Comment: Regarding while trues being counted as "returns on all control paths", what if there is a break or something in the while true loop that ends up making a de-facto while(condition that isn't always true). Any advice regarding the analysis in this specific case?